# Python Dictionary Comprehension with Regular Expression Pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm just practicing basic web scraping using Python and Regex

I want to write a function that takes a string object as input and returns a dictionary where each key is a date as string  like '2017-01-23' (without the quotes tho); and each value corresponding is the approval rating, stored as a floating numbers.

**Here is what the input object(data) looks like**:

As you can see, each record(per day) is denoted by {}, and each key:value pattern followed by ','

```
{"date":"2017-01-23","future":false,"subgroup":"All polls","approve_estimate":"45.46693",  
 "approve_hi":"50.88971","approve_lo":"40.04416","disapprove_estimate":"41.26452",
"disapprove_hi":"46.68729","disapprove_lo":"35.84175"},
{"date":"2017-01-24","future":false,"subgroup":"All polls" 
...................
```

Here's a regex pattern for the dates:

```
date_pattern = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
```

Using this,

```
date_pattern = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
date_matcher = re.compile(date_pattern)
date_matches = matcher.findall(long_string) #list of all dates in string
```

But for the actual approval rating value, this wouldn't work because I'm not looking for a match, but the number that comes after this, which is **45.46693** in this example.

```
approve_pattern = r'approve_estimate\":'
#float(re.sub('[aZ]','',re.sub('["]','',re.split(approve_pattern, data) [1])))
```

The problem with the approve_pattern is that I can only fetch one value at a time. So how can I do this for the entire data and store the approve rating values as float?

Also, I want to only keep records for which **"future":false** to discard predicted values, and only keep the values with "**future":true**.

Please assume all encountered dates have valid approval estimates.

Here's the desired output

```
date_matches=['2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03'] # "future":true filtered out
approve_matches=[47.1,47.2,47.9]

final_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(date_matches,approve_matches)}

final_dict #Desired Output {'2018-01-01': 47.1, '2018-01-02': 47.2, '2018-01-03': 47.9}
```

Comment: Your records are JSON. Why not parse them and access the data fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks very much like JSON, except that it must be enclosed in brackets to form an array. You should use a JSON parser (e.g., `json.loads`) to read it.

Let's say `s` is your original string. Then the following expression results in your dictionary:

```
final_dict = {record['date']: record['approve_estimate'] 
              for record in json.loads("[" + s + "]") 
              if record['future']}
# Empty in your case
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't even know about the json module. One of the points of the exercise was to practice regular expression, but now I can see how ugly it would've been to go with that route